# Virtualenv or PEP370

Tags: python, debian, virtualenv, pep

I have been recommended to follow PEP370 instead of creating virtualenvs.

http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/

Can anyone explain which is a better solution? It seems virtualenvs are redundant since python 2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that PEP (emphasis added):

> Current Python versions don't have a unified way to install packages
>   into the home directory of a user (except for Mac Framework builds).
>   Users are either forced to ask the system administrator to install or
>   update a package for them or to use one of the many workarounds like
>   Virtual Python [1], Working Env [2] or Virtual Env [3].
>
> **It's not the goal of the PEP to replace the tools or to implement
>   isolated installations of Python.** It only implements the most common
>   use case of an additional site-packages directory for each user.

PEP370 solves a similar but still different problem from virtualenv.  PEP370 is about a *per-user* installation, but that doesn't solve the same problems as virtualenv, which creates environments independent of system or user.  I suppose you *could* use PEP370 to replace virtualenv, but that would mean creating a new user account for every new environment you wanted and being very careful to never modify the base istallation, which isn't exactly an easy to use or maintain system.

Comment: I create a user account on my server for every environment (for security, not to replace virtualenvs), and I never had any issue with it yet.

Comment: So every time you want to try out a new library or work on a different project that you'd like to sandbox within your dev environment, you create a new user account?  There's a difference between a sys admin use case and a developer use case.